# Where are the notation3 (n3) debugging tools?

Tags: rdf

Looking for tools for debugging n3. Are we stuck with using XML just because of easier debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"tools" is a rather large area from IDEs, editors, command line...  You can always just run a n3 parser and look at the errors, but in your short question (shorter than this answer) it is hard to suggest anything very specific.  There is an Emacs N3 mode you can use at http://larve.net/people/hugo/2003/scratchpad/NotationThreeEmacsMode.html

Comment: Pretty much as I suspected :) For completeness, I include parsers from the w3c n3 resources page http://www.w3.org/DesignIssues/N3Resources

Comment: That N3 mode is rather old; a up-to-date fork is at https://github.com/kurtjx/n3-mode-for-emacs

Answer (score 1):

Unless you really need the advanced stuff in N3 (formulas, blank predicates, literal subjects etc) you should probably just use Turtle as that's far nicer to work with and far better supported